# Class Design : Threading inside class or outside

Tags: java, android

I have a class `Session` which tracks a bunch of counters and gets persisted to a database. My question is mostly a class design question, and not specific to Android but I'm working on Android, which is only relevant because I want to ensure writing to the database does not happen on *the* main thread.

I'm considering two alternatives for the `persist()` method which writes the session to a db (which could be potentially slow and I'm not overly concerned about whether/when it succeeds):

**Concurrency & Execution inside**

```
public class Session()
{
   //.. getters and setters...

   void persist()
   {
       Runnable r = new Runnable(){
          // Implement logic in run() with slow 
          // db operations
       };
       ExecutorService executor = getExistingExecutor();
       executor.submit(r);
   }
 }
```

**Concurrency & Execution outside**

```
public class Session()
{
   //.. getters and setters...

   void persist()
   {
     // Implement logic in run() with slow 
     // db operations
   }
 }
```

I'm basically wondering from an object design standpoint, what is the best way to wrap up neatly code that could be slow running so that its easy to use? I'm also interested if there is a division of labor issue (The `Session` store values for the session but also knows how to persist itself ... i can't decide if thats nice OO or overly complex).

Comment: How is concurrency controlled inside by returning `Runnable`? Two callers can end up persisting in parallel, causing all sorts of bugs. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that case while i was writing the question, im going to remove it, its the other two cases that are the main cases.

Comment: What do you mean by Execution Outside?

Comment: Well, i meant by comparison to the other example the concurrency controls and execution happen outside the object. In the first example, the logic of the Runnable (the concurrency) is inside the object and the submission to the Executor all happen inside. In the second example, the persistance information would be inside the method, but the other components would have to exist outside of the persist method.

Comment: I am sorry I still can't understand, though I am beginning to think the first option is better, I don't like the idea of leaving concurrency to the caller.

Comment: I vote for outside. Concurrency & exe (not the db access itself) depend on the context of the caller. In the context where you are not allowed to create thread, creating Runnable object would just give overhead. In Android, creating objects is quite costly and there are framework apis that help you manage somewhat concurrency with especially db access in mind (e.g. what happened when low memory kill, orientation change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, it is good design to keep the persistence of an object out of the implementation of an object. You may (will!) want to change how the persistence works without changing the implementation.

Therefore, you should have a separate object that is solely responsible for storing and retrieving the data.